# Why Codename One browser component doesn't work as expected on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, codenameone

I have a simple question in Codename One library, in `browser component` I have a JavaScript method that preview an `alert()` and then call a Java method, this Java method should load the `browser component` with a new content, every thing went fine on simulator, but on the android device only the `pop-up` worked

Here's my Java code

```
JavascriptContext ctx = new JavascriptContext(browser);
    browser.setPage(html, null);//this html is a string and it worked fine
    JSObject window = (JSObject) ctx.get("window");

    window.
            set("openNewAccountPage", (JSFunction) (JSObject self, final Object[] params) ->
            {
                browser.setPage(NewAccountCreator.CreationPage, null);//the CreationPage is a string as html
            });
```

And here's my script that should call Java method

```
function openNewAccountPageJS()
       {
           alert('yes we in it ');                
           window.openNewAccountPage();
       }
```

The `yes we in it` viewed on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to the `setPage` method should be a valid base URL

Comment: thanks eng.Shai for interesting, but the JavaScript code is a part of my HTML page and here's the scenario **1** we have an HTML with a `span` element **2** when the user clicks on this element it should invoke a JavaScript function **3** the JavaScript function shows  an `alert("text")` and then calls a Java method all of this goes well except calling Java method, but this prove that the JavaScript is completely loaded, and for sure i waited a long time before clicking this `span` element @Shai

Comment: There was an issue with null base URL's in Android 6+. It should work with new builds

Comment: Sorry Shai I can't understand the relation between my question and the Android base URL, can you kindly show me that ? and what should i do in this situation ? a lot of HTML pages depend on fixing this error (:- @Shai

Comment: You passed `null` to the second argument in `setPage()` we had a bug in our Android implementation related to passing `null` there that was fixed in the latest update.

Comment: so what should I do ? I just send my JARs to `codename 1 `server so I think it used the latest implementation, can you kindly tell me what should I do ?
some steps (: @Shai

Comment: Is it still happening with new builds?

Comment: Again thank you Shai, if you mean by **new builds** sending JARS to `Code-name 1` server yes it's and I don't knew what should I do ? @Shai

Comment: I think i have good news Eng.Shai I tried the following code and build the **APK** and it worked fine  `browser.setPage(html, "https://javaee-guardians.io");` and also update this `browser.setPage(NewAccountCreator.CreationPage, "https://javaee-guardians.io");` is this the optimal solution ? if it's can you kindly explain it for me and update your answer to be marked as the right answer so similar future questions may benefit from it ? @Shai

Comment: That might work but it also seems you used `alert` which I initially missed. `alert` won't work properly in all platforms as it's a special case JavaScript call that requires special permissions on Android.

Comment: thanks it worked fine can you edit your answer as this  `browser.setPage(html, "any uri such as https://javaee-guardians.io");` so I marked it as the correct answer ?

Comment: Updated the answer